# Is it possible to add a web part without deploying it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have developed a web part in the test environment but i do not have sufficient rights to deploy it. I get the following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': The
>   local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is
>   running and connected to the SharePoint farm.

I cannot give myself admin rights.

Can I add this web part to my site, without deploying it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is custom solution, you cannot add the wsp directly to your site collection. in order to use it to your farm, you have to deploy it. For deploying the wsp, you must be a member of the local Administrators group on the server hosting SharePoint products or use the Farm Admin account.

[Configure and deploy Web Parts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736.aspx#BKMK_DeployConfigure)